# Failed to compute cache key: ".csproj" not found

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-code, csproj

I am new to Docker. I created a Web API using ASP.Net Core using Visual Studio 2019 as well as in VS Code. It works fine. Then I added docker support and added Dockerfile with default values.

When I try to build the docker image, it fails in Visual Studio 2019 as well as in VS Code.

However, If I try to run the Docker image using the Visual Studio 2019 provided option (where I can select docker as run), then the image gets created.
But when I run the build command in Visual Studio 2019 or VS Code i.e.

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile --force-rm -t mytestapp:dev ..
it throws following error<br>
 => ERROR [build 3/7] COPY [myTestApp.csproj, ./]  
Content of my docker file is given below
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myTestApp.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "myTestApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "myTestApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myTestApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myTestApp.dll"]
```

The project structure picture is also attached:

[image: structure]

Comment: Could you give us a picture of your project structure directories? Seem you basiclly run the command in a wrong context.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A simple `docker build` command cannot work with the default Dockerfiles created by Visual Studio because the paths are specified relative to the root of the solution, and not the root of the project.

You can inspect the build output from VS to determine how it builds the image (simplified version):

```
docker build 
  -f "PROJECT_PATH\Dockerfile" 
  -t IMAGE_NAME:dev 
  "SOLUTION_PATH"
```

As you can see, it builds *using* the Dockerfile in the project folder (-f), but *from* the solution folder.

I guess they did it because it has the advantage of keeping each Dockerfile in its own project folder, while letting you reference resources outside that folder using more consistent solution-based paths. Apart from that, it's pretty annoying.

You can move the Dockefile to the solution folder and leave it unchanged, but then the Docker features in VS will stop working as expected. Or you can adopt the VS convention and adapt your scripts accordingly.

Comment: I got here searching for a way to do with with `docker-compse`, and you have to have to set the `build:` -> `context: <the project working directory>`. so like `build: context: ./project dockerfile: Dockerfile` for a directory structure like ./project/Dockerfile from the root.

Comment: I was running into the same. This fixed the problem for me. I moved the Docker config to the solution root folder. In my case, Azure DevOps pipelines was complaining not being able to find the csproj file while Docker was sitting in the project folder instead of the solution folder. Using onpremise Agent, Windows 11, .NET 6.0 and VS 2022.

Answer (score 25):

Try running the command from the parent folder, you can specify the path to the `Dockerfile` using the `-f` flag.

`cd ..`

`docker build -t imagename:tag -f ProjectDir/Dockerfile .`

Docker copy's the `.csproj` and other files from the current location on the host machine, so if you say:

```
COPY ["myTestApp.csproj", "./"]
```

Make sure you are in the right directory on the host machine. The `Dockerfile` created by Docker Support is not always ideal for building images if you use for example other project references but can be a good base.

Comment: Extract in parent level work from my side.

Comment: This worked for me after creating a brand new ASP.NET Docker app.

Comment: This works for me in .Net 7

Answer (score 9):

Run this from your Solution root:

`docker build . -f [ProjectDir]\Dockerfile`

Comment: Nice, It is better to come from solution root

Answer (score 7):

Answer from *[@axtc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12378923/axtck)*k worked for me. The only change required to make it work was to remove the slash:

```
cd ..

docker build -t imagename:tag -f ProjectDir/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: This did the trick for me using an ASP .NET 6 API with the auto generated Docker files, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `docker-compose` to easily create and tear down your setup.

Step 1: Save code below as `docker-compose.yml` one directory higher than your Dockerfile (same path as your project's `.sln` file):

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: [PROJECTNAME]\Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        networks:
            - aspcore-network
    sql-server:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
        networks:
            - aspcore-network

networks:
    aspcore-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Step 2: Add additional services (MYSQL/REDIS/ETC)

Step 3: Open terminal to `docker-compose.yml` location

Step 4: Run `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up -d`

Step 5: When done run `docker-compose down`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .(dot) you included at WORKDIR "/src/."

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by providing the absolute path to the docker command.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, go to the parent directory, with the .sln file and use the docker -f option to specify the Dockerfile to use in the subfolder:

cd \CoreDockerAPI
docker build -f CoreDockerAPI\Dockerfile --force-rm -t myfirstimage .

docker run -it myfirstimage

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I used to solve this problem :

- I checked **Enable Docker** while creating my *.NET 5 Web API Project*.
- For *Docker OS*, I chose **Linux**.
- Then I opened a terminal, navigated to the directory where my project is and typed the following command : `docker build -f Movie.WebAPI\Dockerfile --force-rm -t movie-api:v1 .`

Which gave the following results :

- [for path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdWLp.png)
- [for result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfDt0.png)
- [continuation of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqCvK.png)

As the last step, I ran this command :  `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 movie-api:v1`

Which created the container image.

Now **movie-api** [appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdtEN.png) when I type `docker images`.

Answer (score 0):

In your your VisualStudio settings (C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json by default) you can change the default:

```
"docker.commands.build": "${containerCommand} build --pull --rm -f \"${dockerfile}\" -t ${tag} \"${context}\"",
```

to

```
"docker.commands.build": "${containerCommand} build --pull --rm -f \"${dockerfile}\" -t ${tag} \"${workspaceFolder}\"",
```